# ArcGIS: how to clear selection in Attributes Table with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

ArcGIS: how to clear selection in Attributes Table *with a keyboard shortcut?*  I'm getting tired of going to Options, Clear Selection;  I work with Attribute Tables frequently.

Comment: I was thinking about asking a question for keyboard shortcuts for various actions in ArcMap. Clearing selection would definitely be useful. Also being able to open the properties of a selected layer would be a convenient time saver for me. Maybe people will be able to point to examples of VBA code in which people made their own shortcuts (I know you can do this in Microsoft Office products, ie assign a macro to a keyboard shortcut).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTRL + Backspace should do it for you. More here:  [Keyboard shortcuts for working with tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000006000000.htm)

Edit:  the link I provided is for 10 but it looks like the same shortcut applies to [9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=744&pid=740&topicname=Keyboard_shortcuts_for_working_with_tables).

Comment: Yes there is PDF for users to print out (this use to come with the software but know avaliable as pdf) print small and laminate and keep to hand at the desk until you remember all shortcuts http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-desktop-tips.pdf